# How can I make my anchor tag (this)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've run into a small problem, Ive got a page full of anchor tags and when 1 of them is selected an animation begins, my only problem right now is that I havent defined the anchor tag as (this) so when a series of anchors are selected each of them perform the animation, im not sur right now how I can change the a tag to this though?

My code so far is:

```
$('a').bind('click', function(e){
            $ajax = $('<div id="ajax"></div>');
            $ajax.prependTo('#container');
            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'fast', function(){
                $ajax.animate({ height: 300 }, 'slow', function(){ 
                    $preloader = $('<div id="preloader"></div>').hide();
                    $preloader.prependTo('#ajax').fadeIn('normal');
                });
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        });
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Inside your `click` function, the anchor is automatically set to `this`.

Comment: Not really sure what you want to achieve, but I see several problems: (a) `$ajax` is global (on purpose?). (b) If you make it local then several elements would have the same ID. (c) The element referenced by `$preloader` is never added to the DOM tree.

Comment: If you mean you want only one anchor to cause that code to execute when  clicked, see Brombomb answer, otherwise please be more clear.

Comment: sorry, then how do i write my script in such a way that if another link is clicked then the current code is reversed and then rerun again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not use `var` keywords. This is bad, as all variables you create this way are in the global scope overwriting each other

```
$('a').bind('click', function(e){
    var $ajax = $('<div></div>').prependTo('#container');

    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'fast', function(){
        $ajax.animate({ height: 300 }, 'slow', function(){ 
            $('<div></div>').hide().prependTo($ajax).fadeIn('normal');
            // you can refer to $ajax here! --^^^^^
        });
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you want to add an id to your anchor tag like this

```
<a id="myTag" href=""></a>
```

Then you can access it like this

```
$('#myTag').bind(...
```

You should only use an id once per page (meaning that every id is unique, not that there can only be 1 id per page).

Here's some more info on the [id-selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) from Jquery and more [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) in general